# Why VS Code, C build works but run code not?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

This is my code. When i run the code it sends me an error:

```
helloworld.c:8:16: error: storage size of 'bin' isn't constant

static int bin[size];
```

but when i do a build the exe works. Help pls.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: A *variable-length* array (one where the size is specified with a runtime variable instead of a constant expression) cannot be declared `static`.

Comment: you show an error message for a line that is not in the shown file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializer of a static variable must be known at compilation time. That's why the declaration of *bin* is rejected. Instead you need to declare *bin* as a pointer to an integer and allocate memory dynamically, that is at run-time:

```
int *bin = malloc(size * sizeof *bin);
```

As pointed out by rioV8, you should also free the allocated memory with `free(bin)` when you are done with *bin*.

Comment: if using `malloc` you should also use `free`

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks! Now added to the answer.